# JMS: does it make sense to have a Producer and the related Consumer in the same application?

Tags: java, jms

I'm new to JMS, and would like to know if does it make sense to have a Producer and the related Consumer in the same application? If it does, what are the cases for example?

Comment: By "the same application" do you mean that the application is _only_ exchanging messages with itself and no other applications?

Comment: A producer instance in the application would send some message to a queue and a consumer instance in the same application would consume that message and do other stuff.

Answer (score 1):

It is technically possible to use JMS to exchange messages between components in the same application, but generally speaking it would almost certainly be simpler to just use the language features and APIs provided by Java SE. This would prevent you from having to configure and administer a JMS broker.